# How to split on two panels with the same height

Tags: gwt

Could you tell me how to split page on two parts using SplitLayoutPanel and UI builder. I want to have horizontal line to resize both panels.

I've tried

```
<g:SplitLayoutPanel ui:field="main">
    <g:north size="50" unit="PCT">
        ...
    </g:north>
    <g:south size="50" unit="PCT">
        ...
    </g:south>
</g:SplitLayoutPanel>
```

But I have two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<g:center>` for one of the two panels.

And specify unit in `<g:SplitLayoutPanel unit="PCT">` not in each part (that force you to use the same unit for all parts).

---

If you use N and S, it will put N, S and a center using the remaining space (it doesn't realize that 50% + 50% ocuppies all the available space).

If you use N and center, it will say: use 50% for North and the rest (50%) for center.

Comment: That is better. Now I have one line. How to split on 50% of height

Comment: Doesn't the line appear on 50% of the height? Or the problem is when resizing? I'm not sure of the behaviour at resizing...

Comment: Doesn't the line appear on 50% of the height

Comment: Class SplitLayoutPanel has no appropriate setUnit() method Element <g:SplitLayoutPanel ui:field='main' unit='PCT'>

Comment: You're right. Javadoc says: *This panel is used in the same way as DockLayoutPanel, except that its children's sizes are always specified in Style.Unit.PX units, and each pair of child widgets has a splitter between them that the user can drag.* So you could make it manual.

Comment: How to make it manual? If you want 50% only on initialization, calcule it and set the size to the part (on a DefferedCommand so the widget is already sized). If you want it permanently at 50% (no user resize) then use `DockLayoutPanel` instead.